# Java replaceAll Latex accent with regex

Tags: regex, latex, pattern-matching, java-7

im using Java 7 and Im trying to solve this matcher problem. I know, that I need to use groups or something like this, but it doesnt work still.

Here is the string

```
S. G\'ahler. \ \textit{Untersuchungen \"uber verallgemeinerte
$m$-metrische vor G\'ahler r\"aume. II}
```

and my regex

```
\'(([\s]*[{][\s]*[a][\s]*[}])|([\s]*[a][\s]*))
```

I just think, that it need to edit some to support that groups, because as you can see, this text contains more occurences.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex.getKey());
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
            if (matcher.find()){
                       System.out.println("I find the occurence");
            }
```

Any help I will appreciate, thanks

Comment: Could you specify exactly what you want to match and what you want it to be replaced with?

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve the problem

Just tu ,,redesign" my regex from this

```
\'(([\s]*[{][\s]*[a][\s]*[}])|([\s]*[a][\s]*))
```

to this

```
(\\'(([\s]*[{][\s]*[A][\s]*[}])|([\s]*[A][\s]*)))
```